# How find in mongoose by an array property

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have defined my Conversation scheme like this:

```
    const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
    
    const ConversationSchema = Schema(
      {
        members: {
          type: Array,
        },
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
    
    module.exports = model("Conversation", ConversationSchema);
```

My problem is that when I want to create a conversation model I search first if there is already a conversation.

```
const newConversation = async (req, res = response) => {
  try {
    const { senderId, receiverId } = req.body;

    const conversation = await Conversation.find({
      members: { $in: [senderId, receiverId] },
    });

    if (conversation.length === 0) {
      const dbConversation = new Conversation({
        members: [senderId, receiverId],
      });
      await dbConversation.save();

      return res.status(201).json({
        ok: true,
        conversation: dbConversation
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(403).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: "Conversation already exist",
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: "Please contact with administrator",
    });
  }
};
```

senderId and receivedId are the ids of the users that are in that conversation, but it doesn't work.

How can I make it check if there is already a conversation with both ids?

Comment: What do you mean when it say that it doesn't work? Do you get an error message, or are incorrect results returned, or?  Maybe you are looking for `$all` instead of `$in`?

Comment: alwways return that Conversation already exists

Comment: I've changed $in by $all and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, we came to understand that the thing that wasn't working about the current code was always taking the code path that returned the message that the `"Conversation already exist"`. This meant that the following query was always returning data:

```
const conversation = await Conversation.find({
  members: { $in: [senderId, receiverId] },
});
```

The logic here does not match the logic implied in the question. This syntax uses [the `$in` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to find documents whose `members` array has *at least *one* of* the values passed to it (here the `senderId` and the `receiverId`).

To instead find documents where *both* of those people are present in the `members` array, you want to use [the `$all` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) instead:

```
const conversation = await Conversation.find({
  members: { $all: [senderId, receiverId] },
});
```

Working [Mongo Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oFr3_FSpUcQ).